# Problema con un menú con position fixed , otro elemento se superpone

Tags: html, css

Para analizar mejor el problema agrega img a noticias, mapas y addons

```css
/*Color de los bordes de las tables*/
* {
    border-color: purple; 
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#colorinfo, #colornoticias, #colorpal, #colordis {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    text-shadow: 5px 3px 5px purple;
}
#fondobarra {
    background-color: rgba(97, 6, 100, 0.575) !important;
}
.tablanoticias {
    position: relative;
    left: 85px;
    top: 60px;
}



/*Lado izquierdo*/    
.tablamapas {
    position: relative;
    left: 650px;
    top: -268px;
}

.tabladdons {
    position: relative;
    left: 650px;
    top: -218px;
}
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white
}

.barramove2 {
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="barramove2">
            <table border="3">
            <tbody id="fondobarra">
                <tr id="barrafuente">
                    <td><h1>Contenido</h1></td>
                    <td><h3>&nbsp; -Notix &nbsp;</h3></td>
                    <td>&nbsp; -Server de Discord &nbsp;</a></b></td>
                    <td><b>&nbsp;-Más información &nbsp;</a> </b></td> <td><pre>                             </pre></td> 
                    <td><b>&nbsp;-Contribuir &nbsp;</a></b></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </header>
        <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<section>
    <article>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="IMG/wallpaper4.jpg" width="1295" height="75"></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
    </article>

<article>
    <table border="3" class="tablanoticias">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="xxx" target="_blank"><img src="IMG/walnoticias.jpeg" width="440"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="xxx" id="colornoticias" target="_blank">NOTICIAS </a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="paneltablas">
    <table border="3" class="tablamapas">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="IMG/walmapas.jpg" width="220"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="xxx" id="colormapas" target="_blank">MAPAS</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="3" class="tabladdons">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="MAPAS MC.html" target="_blank"><img src="IMG/waladons.png" width="220"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="xxx" id="coloraddon" target="_blank">ADDONS</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</article>
<br>
<br>    
</body>
</html>
```

Hola estoy aprendiendo CSS, tengo un problema, ya lo intenté y no logro dar con la solución, espero me puedan ayudar:
Estoy haciendo un menú con position fixed, el problema es que llega a un punto donde esta un table
position relative y esta se superpone al menú ocultando su contenido, sólo es con este elemento, los demás elementos no se superponen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ignorar
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Y tu CSS y tu HTML? Es necesario que hagas el [tour] y que agregues [example]

Comment: Disculpa, ya agregué parte del código

Comment: En tu código HTML hay muchos errores. Hay etiquetas sin cerrar, Hay etiquetas de table repetidos innecesarios que estás usando como menú y otro cómo un grid o algo. Esto es una práctica o un sitio web que estás editando?

Comment: Si es una práctica, te puedo ayudar con una maquetación básica de cómo debes crear

Comment: Es práctica, aún estoy aprendiendo, sería de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo prometido es deuda. Creé una plantilla muy básica pero diferente a tu pregunta. Éste te ayudará cómo iniciar con la estructura en el HTML y CSS.

Hay librería CSS muy bueno que se puede usar libremente como base de un proyecto de diseño web. Por ejemplo [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/); y [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) que es muy usado.
Por supuesto, le tenemos a [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) por excelencia en diseño web.

En éste caso use un poco de JavaScript para el menu móvil, ya que es totalmente responsivo.

Es importante entender las funciones de cada etiqueta del HTML, cada cual están exactamente hubicados y en orden. Y para agregar nuevos elementos, agruega con y dentro de la etiqueta `section` por ejemplo:

```
<section class="nuevo">
 <div class="mi-estilo">
   ...
 </div>
</section>
```

```
.nuevo.mi-estilo {
 background-color: red;
}
```

**Nó** se agrega dos etiqueta `header` ni `main`, ni `aside` ni excesivos `br`.

Todos los estilos o diseño de la página tiene y se agrega en la hoja de estilo: CSS.

```css
 

*,html,body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
 outline: none;
}

:root {
 --minHeight: 100px;
}

html {
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 scroll-padding: var(--minHeight);
} 

body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background-color: #212E37;
}

p {
 margin: 10px 0;
 color: #ccc;
}

a {
 color: lightblue;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/* todos los display:block */
section, img, ul, li, .toggle {
 display: block;
}

/* todos los display:flex y align-items:center */
header, .perfil, .perfil a, .menu, ul, li, li a, .sectionHeader, .galeria, .unitario, .menuToggle, footer {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

img {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
} img:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}

header {
 justify-content: space-between;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 5px;
 width: 100%;
 height: var(--minHeight);
 background-color: #2B3743;
}

.perfil, .perfil a {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 max-width:100%;
 max-height: 75px;
}

.perfil .nombrePerfil {
 margin-left: 10px;
 max-width: 50%;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 300;
 color:#ccc;
 text-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
}

.perfil img {
 margin: 0;
 width: 50px;
}

.menuToggle {
 display: none;
}

.menu {
 justify-content: end;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.menu li {
 justify-content: center;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 margin-right: 7px;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 max-height: 75px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: lightblue;
} .menu li a {
 justify-content:  center;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
}

.menu li img {
 opacity: 0.7;
 margin: 0;
 width: auto;
 height: 50px
}

.menu li a .texto {
 display: block;
 position:absolute;
 margin: auto;
 font-size: 13px;
}

main {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
 gap: 10px;
 width: 95%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
}

section {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #2B3743;
}

.section {
 margin-top: calc(var(--minHeight) + 3%);
}

.sectionHeader {
 width:100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

table {
 width:100%;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 color: #ccc;
}

table tr td, table tr th {
 padding: 5px 5px;
}

table .galeria {
 justify-content: center;
}

table .galeria td {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 33.33%;
 height: 150px;
}

table .galeria td img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;      
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #212E37;
}

.unitario {
 overflow: hidden;
 justify-content: center;
}

.unitario img {
 width:100%;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

.unitario .sobre {
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
}

.historia {
 grid-column: 1/4;
 position: relative;
 width: 70%;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}

.historia .sectionHeader {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 5;
 width:100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #123;
}

.historia .sectionHeader ul {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
}

.historia .sectionHeader ul a,
.historia .sectionHeader ul span {
 margin: auto;
 padding: 1px 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #ccc;
 background-color: transparent;
} .historia .sectionHeader ul span {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.historia .sectionHeader ul a.activo {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid green;
 background-color: rgba(0,128,0, 0.3);
}

.historia .seccion {
 padding: 5px;
}

.historia .seccion .encabezado {
 position: sticky;
 top: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 color:#ccc;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #123;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
}

footer {
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: var(--minHeight);
 margin: 5% 0 0 0;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 color:#ccc;
 background-color: #2B3743;
}

/* ESTILOS PARA MOVILES */

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
 
 .menuToggle {
   display: flex;
 }
 
 .menuToggle {
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
 } .menuToggle .hamburguesa,
 .menuToggle .hamburguesa:before, 
 .menuToggle .hamburguesa:after {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #777;
 } .menuToggle .hamburguesa:before {
  margin-top: -8px;
 } .menuToggle .hamburguesa:after {
  margin-top: 8px;
 }
 
 .menu {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
 } .menu.visible {
  right: 0;
  transition-delay: 0s;
 }
 
 .menu .toggle {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
 }
 
 .menu ul {
  flex: none;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  z-index: 5;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: -200px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #212E37, 0 0 30px #212E37;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  transition-delay: 0s;
 } .menu.visible ul {
  margin-right: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
 }
 
 .menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  maf-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
 }
 
 .menu ul li img {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
 }
 
 .menu li a .texto {
  font-size: 100%;
 }
 
 main {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
 }
 
 .historia {
  grid-column: 1/1;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 table .galeria td {
  height: 100px;
 }
 
 
} /* fin estilo móvil */
```

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/maqueta.css">
  <title>Maqueta</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <!-- encabezado -->
  <header>
   
   <div class="perfil">
<a href="#">
 <img src="http://bit.ly/33fY94n">
 <span class="nombrePerfil">Nombre de página</span>
</a>
   </div>
   <button class="menuToggle toggle" id="menuToggle">
<span class="hamburguesa"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="menu" id="menu">
<div class="toggle"></div>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">info</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">
  <img src="http://bit.ly/33fY94n">
  <span class="texto">Nombre de página</span>
  </a></li>
</ul>
   </div>
   
  </header> <!-- /fin encabezado -->
  
  <section class="section">
<table>
 <caption>Tabla diseño galería (desde 3 imágenes por fila)</caption>
 <tr class="galeria">
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3m0M1uA"></a></td>
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3dOnLY8"></a></td>
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3ylrYfr"></a></td>    
 </tr>
 <tr class="galeria">
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3ET0jVG"></a></td>
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3dPtPQ6"></a></td>
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/30l6CSM"></a></td>
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3lXo3QP"></a></td>
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3dPvd5g"></a></td>
 <td><a href="#"><img src="http://bit.ly/3lXahhe"></a></td>    
 </tr>
</table>
   </section>
  
  <!-- contenido general del cuerpo -->
  <main class="area main">
   
   <section>
<table>
 <caption>Tabla diseño básico</caption>
 <tr>
  <th>Primero</th>
  <th>Columna 1</th>
  <th>Negrita</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Segundo</td>
 <td>Columna 2</td>
 <td>Fila 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Tercero</td>
  <td>Columna 3</td>
  <td>Fila 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Cuarto</td>
  <td>Columna 4</td>
  <td>Fila 4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Quinto</td>
  <td>Columna 5</td>
  <td>Fila 5</td>
 </tr>
</table>
   </section>
   
   <section>
<div class="sectionHeader">
 <div class="perfil">
  <a href="#">
   <img src="http://bit.ly/33fY94n">
   <span class="nombrePerfil">Section</span>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="contenido">
 <p>
  Éste es una demostración de una estructura básica de HTML5 y CSS3. no tiene nada espectacular ni llamativo, para eso está <b><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/" target="_blank">Bootstrap 5</a></b>. <br>   
  El diseño del HTML5, el menú y la tabla son básicos y responsivos, y las imágenes son de <b><a href="https://burst.shopify.com/photos" target="_blank">BURST shopify</a></b>, y los enlaces son acortados con <b><a href="https://app.bitly.com/Bk6tjic9upc/bitlinks/" target="_blank">app.bitly.com</a></b> 
 </p>
</div>
   </section>
   
   <section class="unitario">
<img src="http://bit.ly/30l6CSM">
<h3 class="sobre">Una imagen</h3>
   </section>
   
  <section class="historia">
   
   <div class="sectionHeader">
 <ul id="enlaces">
  <span class="nombre">Historia</span>
  <a href="#primera-seccion">Primera</a>
  <a href="#segunda-seccion">Segunda</a>
  <a href="#tercera-seccion">Tercera</a>
</ul>
   </div>

   <div class="seccion">
    <h3 class="encabezado" id="primera-seccion">Primera Sección</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et tellus sagittis, ultricies dui non, vestibulum nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer vehicula rutrum euismod. Mauris dapibus scelerisque tristique. Etiam tempor lobortis dapibus. Morbi sagittis id magna non luctus. Vestibulum nec dui laoreet, mollis arcu sit amet, semper sapien. Curabitur porta egestas ipsum, sit amet pellentesque enim congue vitae. Mauris sodales mattis efficitur. Duis molestie arcu leo. Donec hendrerit turpis a sapien elementum ornare. Curabitur dictum ultrices erat eu dapibus. <br />
        Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam ante est, pellentesque eget tincidunt sed, commodo ut enim. Praesent sodales arcu id diam pharetra, quis accumsan augue rutrum. Vestibulum tincidunt maximus ante viverra consequat. Nulla felis est, porttitor id consectetur blandit, rhoncus in neque. Donec vitae dapibus leo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. <br />
        Integer sollicitudin non neque nec facilisis. Vivamus fringilla felis efficitur, viverra augue sed, scelerisque felis. Curabitur sed justo viverra, bibendum felis tempus, mollis quam. Morbi ac nisl ornare, congue nunc ac, luctus leo. Morbi sollicitudin elit non elementum facilisis. Proin mattis feugiat molestie. Cras et mauris hendrerit, dapibus erat non, pellentesque ligula. Donec sodales elit erat, sit amet vehicula augue consectetur vitae. Sed tristique, nibh ut porta vulputate, purus velit condimentum leo, id elementum leo nunc at velit. Cras eget massa sed massa consequat egestas. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut rutrum augue quis velit tempor, sed viverra ante faucibus. Nullam fringilla laoreet sem, ac laoreet elit ultrices ut. Sed non tortor eget risus malesuada facilisis ut ut sapien.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class="seccion">
    <h3 class="encabezado" id="segunda-seccion">Segunda Sección</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et tellus sagittis, ultricies dui non, vestibulum nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer vehicula rutrum euismod. Mauris dapibus scelerisque tristique. Etiam tempor lobortis dapibus. Morbi sagittis id magna non luctus. Vestibulum nec dui laoreet, mollis arcu sit amet, semper sapien. Curabitur porta egestas ipsum, sit amet pellentesque enim congue vitae. Mauris sodales mattis efficitur. Duis molestie arcu leo. Donec hendrerit turpis a sapien elementum ornare. Curabitur dictum ultrices erat eu dapibus. <br />
        Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam ante est, pellentesque eget tincidunt sed, commodo ut enim. Praesent sodales arcu id diam pharetra, quis accumsan augue rutrum. Vestibulum tincidunt maximus ante viverra consequat. Nulla felis est, porttitor id consectetur blandit, rhoncus in neque. Donec vitae dapibus leo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. <br />
        Integer sollicitudin non neque nec facilisis. Vivamus fringilla felis efficitur, viverra augue sed, scelerisque felis. Curabitur sed justo viverra, bibendum felis tempus, mollis quam. Morbi ac nisl ornare, congue nunc ac, luctus leo. Morbi sollicitudin elit non elementum facilisis. Proin mattis feugiat molestie. Cras et mauris hendrerit, dapibus erat non, pellentesque ligula. Donec sodales elit erat, sit amet vehicula augue consectetur vitae. Sed tristique, nibh ut porta vulputate, purus velit condimentum leo, id elementum leo nunc at velit. Cras eget massa sed massa consequat egestas. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut rutrum augue quis velit tempor, sed viverra ante faucibus. Nullam fringilla laoreet sem, ac laoreet elit ultrices ut. Sed non tortor eget risus malesuada facilisis ut ut sapien.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class="seccion">
    <h3 class="encabezado" id="tercera-seccion">Tercera Sección</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et tellus sagittis, ultricies dui non, vestibulum nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer vehicula rutrum euismod. Mauris dapibus scelerisque tristique. Etiam tempor lobortis dapibus. Morbi sagittis id magna non luctus. Vestibulum nec dui laoreet, mollis arcu sit amet, semper sapien. Curabitur porta egestas ipsum, sit amet pellentesque enim congue vitae. Mauris sodales mattis efficitur. Duis molestie arcu leo. Donec hendrerit turpis a sapien elementum ornare. Curabitur dictum ultrices erat eu dapibus. <br />
        Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam ante est, pellentesque eget tincidunt sed, commodo ut enim. Praesent sodales arcu id diam pharetra, quis accumsan augue rutrum. Vestibulum tincidunt maximus ante viverra consequat. Nulla felis est, porttitor id consectetur blandit, rhoncus in neque. Donec vitae dapibus leo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. <br />
        Integer sollicitudin non neque nec facilisis. Vivamus fringilla felis efficitur, viverra augue sed, scelerisque felis. Curabitur sed justo viverra, bibendum felis tempus, mollis quam. Morbi ac nisl ornare, congue nunc ac, luctus leo. Morbi sollicitudin elit non elementum facilisis. Proin mattis feugiat molestie. Cras et mauris hendrerit, dapibus erat non, pellentesque ligula. Donec sodales elit erat, sit amet vehicula augue consectetur vitae. Sed tristique, nibh ut porta vulputate, purus velit condimentum leo, id elementum leo nunc at velit. Cras eget massa sed massa consequat egestas. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut rutrum augue quis velit tempor, sed viverra ante faucibus. Nullam fringilla laoreet sem, ac laoreet elit ultrices ut. Sed non tortor eget risus malesuada facilisis ut ut sapien.
    </p>
   </div>
  
   </section>
  
  </main> <!-- /fin main (contenido general) -->
  
  <!-- pié de página -->
  <footer>
   <span> Hecho en Diciembre 2021</span>
  </footer> <!-- /fin footer (pié de página) -->
  
  <script>
const toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");  
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");  

const encabezados = document.querySelectorAll('.historia .encabezado');
const enlaces = document.querySelectorAll('#enlaces a');

toggle.forEach(function(click) {  
 
 click.addEventListener("click", verMenu);
 
 function verMenu() {
  menu.classList.toggle("visible");
 }
 
})

// scroll de la sección historia

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entradas, observador) => {
entradas.forEach(entrada => {
    if(entrada.isIntersecting){
        const id = '#' + entrada.target.id;
        
        enlaces.forEach(enlace => {
            enlace.classList.remove('activo');

            const href = enlace.attributes.href.nodeValue;
            if(href === id){
                enlace.classList.add('activo');
            }
        });
    }
});
}, {
threshold: 1,
rootMargin: '0px 0px -50% 0px'
});


encabezados.forEach(encabezado => {
observer.observe(encabezado);
});
</script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Joder, muchas gracias hermano, me servirá de mucho para guiarme, gracias por tomarte el tiempo